# Inconsistency on equals() applied to Vector

Tags: java, equals

```
Vector <Double> x = new Vector<Double>();
Vector <Integer> y = new Vector <Integer>();  
System.out.print(x.equals(y));
```

This prints:

```
true
```

Why? Isn't equals() -by default- supposed to compare if two references point to the same object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`equals` is implemented in `AbstractList`. It goes through elements in the list and returns false if any are not equal. Because your lists have no elements, true is returned.

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
if (o == this)
    return true;
if (!(o instanceof List))
    return false;

ListIterator<E> e1 = listIterator();
ListIterator e2 = ((List) o).listIterator();
while(e1.hasNext() && e2.hasNext()) {
    E o1 = e1.next();
    Object o2 = e2.next();
    if (!(o1==null ? o2==null : o1.equals(o2)))
    return false;
}
return !(e1.hasNext() || e2.hasNext());
}
```

As Tom mentioned in the comments, reading the contract of the `List` Interface you will see that it defines the behavior.

> Returns true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal.

Comment: `Vector` obeys the contract of `List`.

Comment: Rather unrelated question to the actual question but this got me thinking, would it be faster in some determined cases to sort the lists before doing element comparison? You know like 1) check sizes/instanceof/etc. 2) new sorted lists of both 3) oldskool index iteration, compare each pair, fail fast if inequal entries are found.

Comment: @Esko, the semantics you mention sound like a `Set` not a `List`.  In a `List`, order matters.

Answer (score 2):

NO, equals() is not supposed to compare if two references point to the same object.
It compares if the objects referenced are **equal**, mostly that means having the same content.

It only compares for the same object if the method is not implemented for the given Object. In that case the method from `Object` is used with just use the `==` operator.

`==` is the one which compares if it is the same object (instance).

Answer (score 1):

`Vector` has its own `equals` method. It compares its content. And both your `Vector` are empty, so they are equal.

**Please note:** Because of type erasure at runtime there are only two instances of `Vector`.

Comment: @tangens - actually, it is nothing to do with type erasure.  It is everything to do with the specification for Vector.equals(...) / List.equals(...).